# How to rename a table along with projections in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I have to alter many columns in a Vertica table, and decided to drop the table altogether and create a new one. I also need 'undo' scripts ready to revert back the changes if needed (using mybatis migrations).

This is my plan:

```
rename mytable to mytable_backup

create mytable
create projection mytable_super (as select from mytable)


--undo
drop mytable if exists
rename mytable_backup to mytable
```

The original mytable was also created with a projection. The above script gives an error saying projection already exists.

```
 DBCException: SQL Error [4482] [42710]: [Vertica][VJDBC](4482) ROLLBACK:         Projection with base name "mytable_super" already exists
```

I believe when I rename the original table, the underlying projection is not being renamed.

What is the best way to rename a table with projections in vertica? Or what is the best way to back up a table and revert back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [rename the projections](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/ALTERPROJECTIONRENAME.htm) as well.

```
alter projection mytable_super rename to mytable_super_backup;
```

Comment: Is it okay to rename the projections? will that interfere with any of the stuff that vertica does in the background in terms of managing projections/object IDs etc?

Comment: There are no issues with renaming projections unless you have queries that use them directly (like Live Aggregate Projections) or have other scripts that rely on the name.  Nothing internal to Vertica, though.

Comment: Thanks, one more question though -- if later on I add/alter a field in mytable, do I have to also add/alter in the projection also; or is it automatically taken care of?

Comment: It'll be taken care of automagically.  If you add fields, they get added to the superprojection. They will not get added to any non-superprojection, though. There is a CASCADE option but I can't remember if this only cascades new columns to pre-join or all projections. Docs say pre-join.

Comment: I ran into a problem with the above. Now when I drop the mytable_backup  table (cascade), I expected mytable_super_backup to be dropped as well. But seems not. Because when I try to rename another projection to 'mytable_super_backup'  (after dropping mytable_backup with cascade) it says projection already exists. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it might be your AHM.  Try moving the AHM forward (if you aren't doing historical queries using epoch, just `SELECT MAKE_AHM_NOW()`).

Answer (score 0):

For renaming a table, the above answer is the one.

One way to rename a projection, would be to get the projection inside a SQL file. For example:

```
 select CONCAT(CONCAT(projection_schema,'.'),projection_name) from projections where projection_schema like '%one_table%'
```

Then modify it into the following SQL and execute it (and don't forget to run refresh): 
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Projections/UpdatingProjectionsUsingRefresh.htm

Once you have the SQL, you can do `\i /path/of/sql` (inside vertica shell) or you can `/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -f /path/to/sql/that.sql  -U  vertica_user -w vertica_passwd`